# Firebase Function - finished with status code: 204

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.deleteUser = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const userId = context.auth.uid;
  var promises = [];

  // DELETE DATA
  var paths = ['users/' + userId, 'messages/' + userId, 'chat/' + userId, 'like/' + userId];

  paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      recursiveDelete(path).then(  () => {
          return 'success';
        }
      ).catch( (error) => {
        console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
      })
    );
  });

  // DELETE FILES
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  var image_paths = ["avatar/" + userId, "avatar2/" + userId, "avatar3/" + userId];
  image_paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      bucket.file(path).delete().then(  () => {
            return 'success';
          }
         ).catch( (error) => {
          console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
        })
      );
    });

  // DELETE USER
  promises.push(
    admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
    .then( () => {
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
      return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
    })
  );

  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    return true;
  }).catch(er => {
      console.error('...', er);
  });
});




function recursiveDelete(path, context) {
    return firebase_tools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token
    })
    .then(() => {

      return {
        path: path
      }
    }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log('error: ', error);
      return error;
    });
  }
  // [END recursive_delete_function]
```

Im trying to run this function locally from a javascript file:

```
function deleteAccount(userId) {
  fetch(
    `https://us-central1-myappname.cloudfunctions.net/deleteUser/${userId}`,
    { method: "DELETE" }
  );
}
```

But im getting a:

> deleteUser Function execution took 1952 ms, finished with status code:
> 204

Here is my cloud function URL from firebase:

[image]

Comment: Status codes that follow the 2xx pattern are used to indicate that everything went fine. The 204 means that the request was fulfilled and that there is no data in the server response.

Comment: As stated previously 2xx means the execution is successful, you are simply not sending anything back to the client. One more comment, I am not sure why you are using fetch here, as when you work with callable functions, firebase gives you the option to... call them directly from your app like so: `httpsCallable(functions, 'deleteUser')`.

Comment: @Palladium02 when it successfully deletes a user my logs in fire show `Successfully deleted user` when successful it also shows a response code of 200. This works fine with my iOS and Android app, but I also need a way to delete a user locally from my .js file

Comment: @Stf_F with `httpsCallable(functions, 'deleteUser')` how could I pass in a userId?

Comment: All depends on how and what you intend to use this function for. If you want to use the CF as an API I would recommend using a https function instead. You would there have the liberty to use your methods (read DELETE, PATCH, PUT, DELETE etc.) If you want something simpler where a "Delete my account" initiated by your customer in your app actually triggers the deletion of its data, then keep the callable. You wouldn't have to pass the uid from the app as the context would expose it for you.

Comment: @Stf_F how can you manually pass in the `context.auth.uid`?

Comment: Why would you want to pass it when it is already available for you on the serverside?

Comment: @Stf_F In this instance its not, im reading the firebase data in a html table and need to be able to manually run this function passing in a `uid` to delete the user.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh, the docs here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_2, outline how to add a payload to a call a callable function. Cheers.

Comment: You can check [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/making-fetch-requests-happen-a5423852747b) regarding how to input data to HTML page. And you can find in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request), how to parse the JSON data and how to get UID out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer based on my comment and above community members comments for visibility.

Based on the comment from stf_F it is a good idea to use callable functions as it remembers the state, and you don't have to pass any UID to delete the user.
Or you can delcare it also as mentioned in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

> ```
> const text = data.text;
>
> // Authentication / user information is automatically added to the
> request.
>
> const uid = context.auth.uid;
>
> const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
>
> const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
>
> const email = context.auth.token.email || null;index.js
> ```

And you can check how to delete using callable from [the following document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

However, if you prefer using fetch and if you want to know how to get the data in JSON and how to save it in HTML. You can check [this article.](https://medium.com/google-cloud/making-fetch-requests-happen-a5423852747b)
You can use the following example regarding how to structure your fetch

> ```
>     fetch(functionEndpoint)
>         .then(res => res.json()) 
>         .then(function(data) {
>                       /** DO STUFF WITH YOUR DATA **/
>                   }).catch(function(error) {
>                       console.log("Err is:" + err);
>                   });
> ```

And Below example how to use get and fetch the info you need.

> ```
>     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
>         JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); }
> ```

Please don't forget to specify the output in your HTML page

`<pre id="output"> </pre>`

And you can check the [following document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) of how to parse the received JSON data and extract UID for example.